# How to obtain the AssignedLicenses using Microsoft.Graph Client Library

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a working way to read the AssignedLicenses property of a user in the [Microsoft Graph Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph)? I tried the following things, but the AssignedLicenses property always returned null allthough there are licenses assigned to the user

```
// test 1: using "Me"
var lic = client.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result.AssignedLicenses;

// test 2: using the Id of a user
var lic = client.Users["<ID OF THE USER>"].Request().GetAsync().Result.AssignedLicenses;
```

Comment: I just figured out that explicitly selecting the property using "Select" works just fine (var lic = client.Users["<ID OF THE USER>"].Request().Select("assignedLicenses").GetAsync().Result.AssignedLicenses;). However, according to the documentation, select should be used to get a subset of properties. So I assumed not passing "Select" would return everything (including the licenses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using Select is the correct technique here as you found out, viz `Request().Select("assignedLicenses").GetAsync().Result.AssignedLicenses`

On the Graph, Select is used BOTH to reduce the set of properties returned and to bring in properties that are not returned by default.  We do this in an attempt to keep default packet sizes moderately sized and readable and to keep call performance high by not routing every call to every underlying service necessary to fetch data that most callers don't need.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just wondered because the current documentation stated "All of the properties will be returned from an actual call." for user_get (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get)

Comment: Thanks, I'll note that as a doc bug.

Comment: The bug still hasn't been fixed, as it still says the same today.